# WebView doesn't update the content correctly

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

The problem occurs after navigating some pages and try to go back using *window.history.back()*, the screen just doesn't get updated —the last one loaded remains visible—, but the URL in logs does get updated correctly.

InitialPage => SecondPage => ThirdPage [ here the *window.history.back()* occurs ]

The content of the ThirdPage remains visible, but the logged URL using *WebViewClient*'s *onPageFinished* method is correct, that is, the SecondPage's URL gets logged. As the ThirdPage is still showing, if I do another *window.history.back()* —using a button—, it happens again, the ThirdPage remains in screen, but the InitialPage's URL gets logged this time.

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, in the end it must be some JavaScript on the loaded page blocking the proper functioning. I did a simple test with pages of my own and these pages work fine, but the third-party pages not.